# Playing the piano in FF5

Tags: final-fantasy-5

I noticed that when I played the piano in the very first town you go to it came up `Got better at piano` or words to that effect.

So I was just wondering, do you have a 'piano' skill so to speak. I imagine that you will play better songs as you try each piano in each town. Is there any benefit to doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have played on all 8 pianos, you will gain 2 new songs for your bards.

From the [FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gba/930369-final-fantasy-v-advance/faqs/61876) (relevant part in bold):

> The only pianos actually giving you any benefit are the seventh and last piano
>   tunes, but you need to have played all others to actually access these. **The
>   seventh tune inspires the Bard in Crescent to teach you Mana's Paean, the final
>   tune inspires him to teach you Hero's Rime.** In addition, your piano skills soar
>   to unknown heights. Sure, it's useless versus Exdeath, but wouldn't you rather
>   be an erudite homo universalis than a rampaging brute?

Comment: Are the names of those songs the same on the PS1 version and the original RPGe translation?

Comment: I would posit that, given that they allowed a team of four single-class Bards to beat Exdeath, they are not useless. :P